# How to make data entered by user to appear below headers

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

This is my code for entering student details. Once the user has entered the details and inputs yes, the details are exported to StudentDetails.csv (Microsoft Excel) where it should go below the headers but ends up going somewhere else.

```
def EnterStudent():
    uchoice_loop = False
    ask_loop = False
    while uchoice_loop == False:
            surname = raw_input("What is the surname?")
            forename = raw_input("What is the forname?")
            date = raw_input("What is the date of birth? {Put it in the format D/M/Y}")
            home_address = raw_input("What is the home address?")
            home_phone = raw_input("What is the home phone?")
            gender = raw_input("What is their gender?")
            tutor_group = raw_input("What is their tutor group?")
            email = (forename.lower() + surname.lower() + ("@school.com"))
            print(surname+" "+forename+" "+date+" "+home_address+" "+home_phone+" "+gender+" "+tutor_group+" "+email)
            ask = raw_input("Are these details correct?"+"\n"+"Press b to go back, or yes to add entered data on your student.").lower()
            if ask == "yes":
                    f = open("StudentDetails.csv","rt")
                    lines = f.readlines()
                    f.close()
                    lines.append(surname+","+forename+","+date+","+home_address+","+home_phone+","+gender+","+tutor_group+","+email+"\n")
                    f = open("StudentDetails.csv", "w")
                    f.writelines(lines)
                    f.close()
                    uchoice_loop = True
                    printMenu()
            elif ask == "b":
                    uchoice_loop = False
            else:
                 print("Plesase enter 'b' to go back or 'yes' to continue")
```

This is my csv file.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sxSya.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please edit your post to provide a bit more information. Where is the data going to instead? What error messages do you receive? This will help us help you.

Answer (score 0):

There's a few things you can do to make this work. You dont need to open the StudentDetails.csv and read all of the lines. Instead you can make a lines string variable and append it the the StudentDetails.csv like in the example below

```
#f = open("StudentDetails.csv","rt")
#lines = f.readlines()
#f.close()
lines = surname+","+forename+","+date+","+home_address+","+home_phone+","+gender+","+tutor_group+","+email

# the "a" appends the lines variable to the csv file instead of writing over it like the "w" does
f = open("StudentDetails.csv", "a") 
f.writelines(lines)
f.close()
uchoice_loop = True
```

Answer (score 0):

Eric is right in that you best open the file in append-mode (see https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#open) instead of cumbersomely reading and rewriting your file over and over again.

I want to add to this that you probably will enjoy using the standard library's `csv` module as well (see https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/csv.html), especially if you want to use your output file in Excel afterwards.

Then, I'd also advise you to not use variables for while loop conditionals, but learning about the `continue` and `break` statements. If you want to break out of the outer loop in the example, research `try`, `except` and `raise`.

Finally, unless you really have to use Python 2.x, I recommend you to start using Python 3. The code below is written in Python 3 and will not work in Python 2.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- codig: utf-8 -*-

import csv


def enterStudent():
    b_or_yes = 'Press b to go back, or yes to save the entered data: '
    while True:
        surname = input('What is the surname? ')
        forename = input('What is the first name? ')
        date = input(
            'What is the date of birth? {Put it in the format D/M/Y} ')
        home_address = input('What is the home address? ')
        home_phone = input('What is the home phone? ')
        gender = input('What is the gender? ')
        tutor_group = input('What is the tutor group? ')
        email = forename.lower() + surname.lower() + '@school.com'
        studentdata = (
            surname,
            forename,
            date,
            home_address,
            home_phone,
            gender,
            tutor_group,
            email)
        print(studentdata)
        while True:
            reply = input('Are these details correct?\n' + b_or_yes).lower()
            if reply == 'yes':
                with open('studentdetails.csv', 'a', newline='') as csvfile:
                    studentwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, dialect='excel')
                    studentwriter.writerow(studentdata)
                break
            elif reply == 'b':
                break


if __name__ == '__main__':
    enterStudent()
```

Best of luck!